# Find a minimal $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x)-T_Nf(x,0)| \le 10^{-6}$ without using Lagrange

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x):=\cos(x)e^x$.
>
> Find a minimal $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$|f(x)-T_Nf(x,0)| \le 10^{-6} \quad (x \in [-\frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{10}]).$$

I've encountered this question here on Math SE before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509889/how-to-show-leftfx-t-n-fx-0-right-leq-10-6)) but I would like to know how to solve it without using Lagrange.

After identifying all the derivatives up to $f^{(4)}$ (for instance), I got

$$\left|\,\cos(x)e^x-(-\frac16 x^4-\frac13x^3+1)\,\right| = \left|\,\cos(x)e^x+\frac16 x^4+\frac13x^3-1)\,\right| \le \\ \cos(\frac{1}{10})e^{1/10}+ \frac16 \cdot \frac{1}{10^4} + \frac13 \cdot \frac{1}{10^3} -1 \approx 0.11,$$

which isn't even close. So how to approach it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless the series is alternating and monotonically decreasing in magnitude, which it isn't in this situation, you're going to need one of the Taylor remainders to estimate the tail (unless you have a black box way to evaluate $f$ itself, in which case it is sort of pointless to use a remainder estimate in the first place). Lagrange is one, the integral formula is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to use complex numbers. You have 
$$
e^x\cos x=\operatorname{Re} e^x(\cos x+i\sin x)=\operatorname{Re} e^{(1+i)x}=\operatorname{Re} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1+i)^kx^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{[(1+i)^k+(1-i)^k]x^k}{2k!}.
$$
Then, for $|x|\leq 10^{-1}$, and using a fairly crude estimate at the end, 
\begin{align}
\left|e^x\cos x-\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{[(1+i)^k+(1-i)^k]x^k}{2k!}\right|
&=\left|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac{[(1+i)^k+(1-i)^k]x^k}{2k!}\right|\\ \ \\
&\leq \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac{|1+i|^k10^{-k}}{k!}\\ \ \\
&= \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt2)^k10^{-k}}{k!}\\ \ \\
&\leq\frac1{(N+1)!}\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty (0.15)^k\\ \ \\
&=\frac{1}{(N+1)!}\frac{0.15^{N+1}}{1-0.15}\leq1.2\,\frac{0.15^N}{(N+1)!}.
\end{align}
The last expression has values 
$$
\begin{array}
\text{N} &\hspace{1cm} 1.2\,\frac{0.15^N}{(N+1)!}\\
\hline1& \hspace{1cm} 0.09\\
2&\hspace{1cm}0.0045\\
3&\hspace{1cm}0.000169\\
4&\hspace{1cm}5.06E-06\\
5&\hspace{1cm}1.27E-07\\
\end{array}
$$
So  $N=5$ is enough. I don't think you can guarantee that it is minimal without "cheating" in some sense, i.e. having a priori a good estimate of $\cos 0.1\,e^{0.1}$.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:
$$\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^x\cos x\right|_{x=0}=\Re\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{(1+i)x}\right|_{x=0}=\left.\Re(1+i)^ne^{(1+i)x}\right|_{x=0}=\Re\left(\sqrt2e^{\pi i/4}\right)^n=2^{n/2}\cos{\frac{n\pi}4}$$
So you have the first derivative wrong.

There is also an exact expression for the error:
$$\begin{align}f(x)-f(0)&=\int_0^xf^{\prime}(t)dt=\left.-(x-t)f^{\prime}(t)\right|_0^x+\int_0^x(x-t)f^{\prime\prime}(t)dt\\
&=f^{\prime}(0)\cdot x+\int_0^x(x-t)f^{\prime\prime}(t)dt\\
&=f^{\prime}(0)\cdot x+\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(0)}2x^2+\frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)}6x^3+\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{24}x^4+\frac1{24}\int_0^x(x-t)^4f^{(5)}(t)dt\end{align}$$
But it really isn't all that much of an improvement in this case. Here
$$\left|\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^x\cos x\right|\le\left|(1+i)^ne^{(1+i)x}\right|\le2^{n/2}e^{0.1}$$
So either way you get an estimate of
$$\frac{(0.1)^5}{5!}2^{5/2}e^{0.1}\approx5.2\times10^{-7}$$
The actual error is
$$e^{0.1}\cos(0.1)-(1+0.1-\frac13(0.1)^3-\frac16(0.1)^4)=-3.33\times10^{-7}$$
So I think your biggest problem was when you set $f^{\prime}(0)=0$ when in fact $f^{\prime}(0)=1$.